# dplyr group_by() doesn't show the result in group form

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I am trying to group_by a data frame based on 4 variables and find an average of the fifth variable. the code I have works; however, it doesn't show the result as one row. so for example:

```
shift <- c(0,0,0)
age <- c(14,14,14)
site <-c(4,4,4)
level <-c(5,5,5)
time<- c(50,60,70)

  shift age site level time
1     0  14    4     5   50
2     0  14    4     5   60
3     0  14    4     5   70
```

I run the code below:

```
data <- data.frame(shift,age, site, level, time)
data <- data %>% group_by(shift, age, site, level) %>%  mutate(Ave_time=mean(time))
```

**the ideal result I want** is in this form

```
  shift   age  site level  time Ave_time
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1     0    14     4     5    50       60
```

but what I get is:

```
  shift   age  site level  time Ave_time
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1     0    14     4     5    50       60
2     0    14     4     5    60       60
3     0    14     4     5    70       60
```

can you please advise how I can fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Did you want `summarise` instead of `mutate`?

Comment: `mutate`just adds a new column your your data. Maybe you are looking for `summarise`?

Comment: @AllanCameron, thanks, it worked. I should have used summarise_ instead.

Comment: @stefan, thanks, using summarise fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use `aggregate` instead ?

```
library(dplyr)

aggregate(.~shift+age+site+level, data, mean) %>%  mutate(Ave_time=mean(time))

# shift age site level time Ave_time
# 1     0  14    4     5   60       60
```

Comment: Thanks, Liman, this approach also works; however, I guess using summarise, as recommended by Stefan and Allan, would be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @ Allan Cameron and @stefan in the comments. Using `summarise` function instead of `mutate` will resolve the issue